# Purposes of maintaining the Creator ID in Windows

Tags: windows, process

Windows maintains only the creator process ID, not a link back to the creator of the creator, and so forth. Then, what all could be the possible purposes of maintaining the Creator ID?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible to keep track of an entire tree using only child->parent references and references to the leaves.  I don't know whether this is what Windows does.  However, there are certainly [tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) that show the full process tree, so that information is maintained.

Comment: No, Windows doesn’t keep track of more than just the parent process 
ID. And my attempt is to understand the OS behavior rather than finding a tool to work on the process tree. Also, these tools show the process tree only if the grand-parents-parent-child exist. If one of them above the child exits, then the node down from that point gets left-justified.

Comment: If you're positive no other information is maintained, then you've answered your own question.  It needs enough information to understand the structure of the process tree (for tools like that or other purposes, such as a program knowing its own ancestors).  And clearly it *has* enough information.

Comment: No, Matthew. I guess my question did not get conveyed to you correctly. I will try to re-phrase in a while. And regarding a program knowing its own ancestors : Each process points to its parent or creator process. However, if the parent exits, this 
information is not updated. Therefore, it is possible for a process to point to a nonexistent parent. This is not a problem, as nothing relies on this information being present.

Comment: Also, I guess we are mixing two different things unintentionally. One is that Windows (the OS) maintains the relationship. The second one is that a process in the OS maintains an ID to its parent. I wanted to know about the first one as it seems like the OS is not keen in maintaining the tree (the grandparent1->grandparent2->parent->child). If grandparent2 exits parent will no longer be a child of grandparent1. In such case then why the OS is still maintain the immediate creator ID?

Comment: There is a line of thinking that says you don't keep track of information you don't need.  Keeping track of the immediate parent is necessary to provide IPC mechanisms.

Comment: Yeah I agree with your first statement. But IPC can be between any process irrespective of the child-parent relationship, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you have to start somewhere.  The parent-child relationship is fundamental; the rest (grandparent, sibling, etc.) can be figured out based on that (with caveats) so there is no need to track it.